# Android ICS build errors

Tags: android, build-process

i'm trying to build Android ICS on i.MX6q board using 64-bit ubuntu 12.04
building android image is giving the following errors

```
============================================
PLATFORM_VERSION_CODENAME=REL
PLATFORM_VERSION=4.0.4
TARGET_PRODUCT=sabresd_6dq
TARGET_BUILD_VARIANT=user
TARGET_BUILD_TYPE=release
TARGET_BUILD_APPS=
TARGET_ARCH=arm
TARGET_ARCH_VARIANT=armv7-a-neon
HOST_ARCH=x86
HOST_OS=linux
HOST_BUILD_TYPE=release
BUILD_ID=UNKNOWN
BUILD_NUMBER=eng.vvdn.20130527.100030
============================================
No private recovery resources for TARGET_DEVICE sabresd_6dq
host Executable: acp (out/host/linux-x86/obj/EXECUTABLES/acp_intermediates/acp)
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.5.3/libstdc++.so   when searching for -lstdc++
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.5.3/libstdc++.a when searching for -lstdc++
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.5.3/libgcc_s.so when searching for -lgcc_s
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.5.3/libgcc_s.so when searching for -lgcc_s
/usr/bin/ld: i386:x86-64 architecture of input file `/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.5.3/crtbegin.o' is incompatible with i386 output
/usr/bin/ld: i386:x86-64 architecture of input file `/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.5.3/crtend.o' is incompatible with i386 output
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [out/host/linux-x86/obj/EXECUTABLES/acp_intermediates/acp] Error 1
```

please help to resolve....